# In order Hashtable traversal

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, hashtable

I wrote a short static method inside my class to iterate over some `Hashtable`s I have in order of the keys (`string`s) but I'm getting a weird compiler error. Here's the method in question:

```
public static DictionaryEntry inorderHashtable(Hashtable ht) {
    string[] keys = ht.Keys.Cast<string>().ToArray<string>();
    Array.Sort(keys);

    foreach (string key in keys) {
        yield return new DictionaryEntry(key, ht[key]);
    }
}
```

This is later used inside the class like this:

```
foreach(DictionaryEntry dentry in inorderHashtable(myTable)) { /* ... */ }
```

Here's the error I'm getting from VS2008: `'ns.myclass.inorderHashtable(System.Collections.Hashtable)' cannot be an iterator block because 'System.Collections.DictionaryEntry' is not an iterator interface type`

What's a way around this error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that you could just `return ht.Keys.Cast<string>().OrderBy(key => key).Select(key => ...);` and change the return type accordingly.

Comment: `HashTable` is also obsolete at this point.  You should really be using a `Dictionary` if at all possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your method needs to have the return type `IEnumerable<DictionaryEntry>`.

Basically, by using `yield return` instead of `return`, you're not returning *one* `DictionaryEntry`, you're (potentially) returning *many*.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dscyy5s0.aspx) if you're unsure what's going on.

Comment: I got the error "The non-generic type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' cannot be used with type arguments' but it's working correctly with just returning IEnumerable. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @David You should really fix the code to use the generic `IEnumerable` interface.  My guess is you just need to add a `using` for the generic  namespace for it to work.

Comment: @Servy, indeed that was the problem with the `using`. Thanks again.